# How can I *do something* if it matches both elements in a list?

Tags: python

I am passing this 4 dictionaries which consist different types of test cases.

```
 1. Manual-Smoke         ==> d1
 2. Manual- Regression   ==> d2 
 3. Automated-Smoke      ==> d3
 4. Automated-Regression ==> d4
```

Now I am passing a list of 4 dictionaries into a function which
    gives me count. **My problem is to get the count of all "MANUAL" cases &
    "AUTOMATED" cases**

I have a list say `input_list =[d1,d2,d3,d4]`. Now, I have to execute 6 scenarios:

```
 1. d1 && d2
 2. d3 && d4
 3. d1
 4. d2
 5. d3
 6. d4
```

So If any of the above-mentioned scenarios occur then I will *do something*. So, I am using the following code which covers 4 scenarios but never covers **the first two**

```
for d in dict:
  if d ==d1 and d==d2:
    print 'Scenario:1 ==> d1 && d2'
  elif d==d3 and d==d4:
    print 'Scenario:2 ==> d3 && d4'
  else:
    if d==d1:
      print 'Scnario 3: ==> d1'
    elif d==d2:
      print 'Scnario 4: ==> d2'
    elif d==d3:
      print 'Scnario 5: ==> d3'
    elif d==d4:
      print 'Scnario 6: ==> d4'
```

I know my loop never falls into `Scenario 1` & `Scenario 2` conditions as my list doesn't include `(d1,d2) (d3,d4)`.

Could you guys please help me to improve the code?

Comment: `d ==d1 and d==d2` can be true only if `d1 == d2`. Are you sure of this?

Comment: There seems to be a bit of logic issue in your code. Can you tell us what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: what is d1 and d2 in dict variable?

Comment: I am passing this 4 dictionaries which consist different types of test cases. 

`1. Manual-Smoke 2. Manual- Regression 3. Automated-Smoke 4. Automated-Regression`

Now I am passing a list of 4 dictionaries into a function which gives me count. **My problem is to get the count of all "MANUAL" cases & "AUTOMATED" cases**

Comment: It's more a `logic problem` than a `code problem`. Show more info on your logic.

Comment: Can u see second part of my solution ? this is according to your problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

We are iterating `list` type data structure. so give meaningful name to variable.  I have given `input_list =["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]`

When we iterate `list` i.e. `input_list` variable then one item from the list will be iterate. So we can not do `if d ==d1 and d==d2:` because we are comparing one item with two different condition which is always false.

What I understand from your code is that, We have one list and according to some hard-code condition we have to execute some scenario.

**Demo:**

```
input_list =["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]



if "d1" in input_list and "d2" in input_list:
  print 'Scenario:1 ==> d1 && d2'
elif "d3" in input_list and "d4" in input_list:
  print 'Scenario:2 ==> d3 && d4'
elif "d1" in input_list:
  print 'Scnario 3: ==> d1'
elif "d2" in input_list:
  print 'Scnario 4: ==> d2'
elif "d3" in input_list:
  print 'Scnario 5: ==> d3'
elif "d4" in input_list:
  print 'Scnario 6: ==> d4'
```

---

Suppose list contains dictionary items.

**Demo**

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
d3 = {}
d4 = {}

input_list =[d1, d2, d3, d4]


for item in input_list:
    if "d1" in item and "d2" in item:
        print 'Scenario:1 ==> d1 && d2'
    elif "d3" in item and "d4" in item:
        print 'Scenario:2 ==> d3 && d4'
    elif "d1" in item:
        print 'Scnario 3: ==> d1'
    elif "d2" in item:
        print 'Scnario 4: ==> d2'
    elif "d3" in item:
        print 'Scnario 5: ==> d3'
    elif "d4" in item:
        print 'Scnario 6: ==> d4'
```

**Notes:**

1. Do not use reserved key words of Python. `dict` is keyword in Python.

Comment: The second solution seems to be true but while implementing your solution I am getting following error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: A dictionary cannot be hashed. Might be you are adding/checking key in dictionary data structure which key is type of dictionary.  Need your code to give you correct reason. (vivekbsable@gmail.com)

Comment: The second approach seems like more inclined towards my problem.  However, there is some error in your code. While you are iterating over each item in a list you are simultaneously checking two dictionaries in each item.

For the first iteration of `item` in `input_list`, it will only get `d1` while the `if condition` checks where `d1` & `d2` both exists in an `item` 

I modified your code this way:

`if  d1 and d2 in [x for x in input_list]:
      print 'Scenario 1'
`

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
for d in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  print d
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
```

So at each time through the loop the variable `d` has only one value. It can never be both `1` and `2` at the same time.

But this is the guard for one of your tests. I.e. you test `d==1 and d==2` modified to fit my example, which will never be the case.

Having said that, how could your code be improved? Take a look at the following code

```
1 in [2, 3]
```

This will print

```
False
```

We can learn from this that `in` can determine if an element is contained in an array. So instead of looping over the array, try to check for the different cases. So your compound test could look like `1 in dict and 2 in dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scenario_map={}   

for d in dict :
    scenario_map[d] = 1 

if scenario_map[d1] == 1 and scenario_map[d2] == 1:
    #execute scenario 1
elif scenario_map[d3] == 1 and scenario_map[d4] == 1 :
    #execute scenario 2 
elif scenario_map[d1] == 1 :
    #execute scenario 3 
elif scenario_map[d2] == 1 :
    #execute scenario 4 
elif scenario_map[d3] == 1 :
    #execute scenario 5 
elif scenario_map[d4] == 1 :
    #execute scenario 6
else :
    #No scenario to execute
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but my input is a list, not a dictionary.